# Почему в mysql при update передаются пустые значения?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть две переменные, в которых есть значения и их нужно передать в БД путем функции update для sql:

```
function update_telegram_info($telegram_user_id, $telegram_username, $info_user_id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "UPDATE users_projects
        SET username = :telegram_username 
        AND user_id = :telegram_user_id
        WHERE info_user_id = :info_user_id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':telegram_user_id', $telegram_user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':telegram_username', $telegram_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':info_user_id', $info_user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$get = get_user_info($user_id);

$telegram_user_id = $get['user_id'];
$telegram_username = $get['info_username'];
$info_user_id = $get['info_user_id'];

update_telegram_info($telegram_user_id, $telegram_username, $info_user_id);
```

Переменные `$telegram_user_id` и `$telegram_username` не пустые, переменная `$info_user_id` передается, чтобы значения записались в нужные строки

Так это выглядит в БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения должны записаться в 1 и 4 строки

Не понимаю, почему там стоят нули, даже проверил типы данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SET username = :telegram_username AND user_id = :telegram_user_id` можно ссылку на источник, где вы видели такой синтаксис SET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял в чем проблема, вместо `SET username = :telegram_username AND user_id = :telegram_user_id` нужно было написать `SET username = :telegram_username, user_id = :telegram_user_id`